# Unable to freez list header row

Tags: 2010, list-view

I want to freeze the header row of the list.

I found [this](http://bkemmler.blogspot.in/2010/02/sharepoint-list-fixed-header.html) link to do so and I put the code in the Content Editor Web Part of the same view page.

My problem is that I am getting the scroll bars withing the view but the headers are not freeze.

Snapshot -- [image: Document view without headers]

What should I do ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works with IE and Chrome browser. I hope it will work with all the browser also.

Thanks goes to http://salzerdesign.com/  for his post http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

List of things to do:
1. You need to reference jQuery file in you page
2. You need to define your own selector to select your table:

> var $table = $("#onetidDoclibViewTbl0");

Here is the code that you can be included in content editor webpart to have fixed header:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*top most wrapper for fixed header solution*/
.fh-outerWrapper
{
    position:relative;
}

/* table wrapper*/
.fh-tableWrapper
{
    overflow:auto;
    height:300px;
}

/*the wrapper for 'th' content*/
.fh-thRow .fh-thContentWrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.fh-bg
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#D5ECFF;

}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

// Get table reference
// TODO: apply your selector to select the table
var $table = $("#onetidDoclibViewTbl0");

// Get table's header row reference
var $hdr = $("tr.ms-viewheadertr:first", $table);

// Wrap table in div
$table.wrap("<div class='fh-tableWrapper' />");

// Wrap the table's wrapper in another div
// This is top most wrapper for fixed header table
$('.fh-tableWrapper').wrap("<div class='fh-outerWrapper' />");

// Now add another div within top most wrapper
// to acts as header background
$('.fh-outerWrapper').prepend("<div class='fh-bg' />");

// Put content of each table's header colmumn 'th'
// value/data in a div, so that it abosolute position is
// applied to it
$('th',$hdr).wrapInner("<div class='fh-thContentWrapper'/>");

// Add css class so that styling can be applied
$hdr.addClass("fh-thRow");
$table.addClass('fh-table');

});

</script>
```

Comment: The check un-check perfectly works in firefox but not properly working in IE..

Comment: I tested and found it works fine. Try to refresh the page and then check. Check this video for my test: http://screencast.com/t/YAxm9Gl9

Comment: Thank you sir, I saw the video and tested.. Works perfectly :-)

Comment: It works perfectly in SP2010 but sir, when I pasted the content of the CEWP inside the SP2013 it reflects nothing.

Comment: I have described that you need a selector to select the table, "var $table = $("#onetidDoclibViewTbl0");". If you show me the html code of you SharePoint page, I can help you. You can put your code http://pastebin.com/ and let me know the link.

Comment: I pasted the same code you provided in the answer and it was running successfully, but as you are saying that I have to give the `onet` id in `var $table = $("#onetidDoclibViewTbl0")`. I wrote the list ID of the document library there, but now it's not working. Is the list id and onet id are same, if they are not then please let me know how to get it...

Comment: You just need to define for selector for jQuery and it could be anything class, id attribute etc. You just paste the code at pastebin and let me know the link.

Comment: Though my code is [here](http://pastebin.com/faNbVF6W) ..

Comment: I want to see the HTML code of you page that has fixed header not working. If you are using IE, right click on the page and select "View Source" and then copy the page's HTML code and send me using pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the link and found it is referencing to [this](http://kjellsj.blogspot.in/2009/06/sharepoint-jquery-scrolling-view-with.html) , and if you see that link you notice that it is for SharePoint 2007/WSS 3.0.
I check same thing for SharePoint 2010 and found that SharePoint 2010 is using iframe, so we cannot use it any more. If SharePoint would not use iframe it worked fine or by making some tweak it could be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for information sir, 
any way to solve this? @AmitKB

Comment: Can you tell me how did you added the list to page? In my case I see the list in iframe and if your list is not in iframe then it can be done.

Comment: OK..

I created one document library called `docs` then click on it to view its contents, now I am currently on `Docs\Forms\AllItems.aspx` page. Then clicked on Edit Page and added a new web part above the view of document library. Selected `HTML Form Web Part` and placed the code in it.

Comment: Replaced the List Id and View Id also.

Comment: Sir, one more help I need from you is that I found [this another solution](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2013/03/freezing-title-row-of-sharepoint-2010.html) it works perfectly, but the problem is that when I edit the page in SharePoint Design and preview it in browser for 3-4 times the view disappears, i.e. the error arises displaying correlation ID `Unable to display this web part`. @AmitKB

Comment: I did few test and found your previous solution not working because of IE 9+ browser. I have fixed that but still testing it and will post the answer today if I got time.